# Ford Focus SE A/C-Heater blower motor not working

Tags: ford, focus, heater-blower

Ford Focus 2008 SE Blower motor and resistor location?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the glovebox; it's on a bracket on the HVAC housing.

[image]